# как создать сервер через swagger и использовать в разных платформах?

Tags: .net, spring-boot, rest, .net-core, swagger

Имеется открытая API (OpenweatherMap). как можно сделать сервер, применяя swagger, и далее использовать во фрэймворках для работы (spring, .net core). Извините, если употребляю неправильные термины, я новичок.
Нашел данный ресурс, но не понимаю, как его использовать:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/server-stub-generator-howto
помогите плиз

Comment: Курите доки! Сначала для  API (OpenweatherMap), затем определяйтесь в какой технологии вы собираетесь получать данные (рекомендую JSON), потом курите доки на swagger (рекомендую JSON), после чего определяйтесь с технологией (spring, .net core), и делайте. Вы хотите получить такой ответ? Если нет, то тогда определитесь чего хотите, а затем пошагово, по конкретным вопросам, приходить сюда.

Comment: @Monomax, я был знаком с OpenweatherMap. Я оформил его в swagger. в JSON формате, а не технологии. Я определился с технологиями, и я их назвал- это spring  .net.core. В swaggere есть генератор серверов, но он не работает. На github нашел генератор, ссылку я на него привел, но я не понимаю, как в нем работать. Куда еще конкретнее вопросы задавать?

Comment: @Mikhail ссылка, которую вы привели к запросе - это ссылка на утилиту для генерации серверной стороны. Вы сами хотите кому-то предоставлять API OpenweatherMap?  Или вы хотите подключаться к OpenweatherMap.org и тянуть с них данные? Если последнее - то вам нужен не генератор сервера, а генератор клиентского кода (т.к. ваше приложение будет являться клиентом для API). Клиент можно сгенерировать через https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#to-generate-a-sample-client-library (Java, C#) или https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag (C#)

Comment: @PashaPash, нужна именно серверная сторона :) Хочу сам предоставлять кому-нибудь API OpenweatherMap :)

Comment: @Mikhail тогда нужно сразу определиться на чем именно писать - spring-boot и .net core как-то не особо сочетаются друг с другом (одно - java, второе .net). А дальше - берете утилиту, натравливаете ее на json по инструкции (по вашей ссылке). Полученный код копируете в проект на java или .net (смотря что выбрали), и дописывает реализацию. Если в процессе что-то пойдет не так - оформляйте в виде отдельных вопросов

Comment: @PashaPash я понял, спасибо большое! Я в курсе, что " spring-boot и .net core как-то не особо сочетаются друг с другом" )) я их привёл для примера.